# Sending application/xml POST message to REST API doesn't work

Tags: java, rest, post, jaxb, jax-rs

This is the POST method with JAX-RS annotations:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response storeUser(User user) {

   boolean wasStored = JPAUserStore.storeUser(user);

   if (wasStored) {
      return Response.ok("User was stored.").build();
   } else {
      return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();   
   }

}
```

And this is the class User with JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public User {

  @XmlElement(name = "Name")
  protected String name;

  @XmlElement(name = "Address")
  protected String address;

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
     return this.name;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
     this.address = address;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
     return this.address;
  }

}
```

The REST web service runs on a Jetty. 
When I send a request message (using RESTClient Firefox plugin) with content type "application/xml" and this body

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <User>
    <Name>Max</Name>
    <Address>Main Street 12</Address>
 </User>
```

to the appropriate resource a 400 Bad request will be returned. According to the log the method JPAUserStore.storeUser(...) was not executed.

What is the reason, why the method annotated with @POST will be not executed and OK returned?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are sending a POST request with the Firefox plugin? If so, my bet would be that it's a problem with the request URI. What URI are you POSTing to?

Comment: The same resource also contains a @GET method. A GET message sent by the REST Client returns a OK and the desired XML code, so the resource should be not the problem.

Comment: Did you check the `storeUser` method to see why it's returning `false`?

Comment: I have changed the returned status if wasStored = false to a other status and still get a Bad request.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting with status 400?

Comment: The message is: Problem accessing /api/users. Reason: <pre>Bad Request</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the root element for your `User` class will be `user`, you need to use `@XmlRootElement(name="User")` to match your XML document.